# Errors in pool.map in django just return the fact that there was an error, not where it was in the mapped function

Tags: python, django, python-multithreading, django-errors

I have some fairly hefty code in Django and am using pool.map() to parallelize it.

A super trivial breakdown of it would be something like:

```
def addNumbers(server):
    conn = Connection(server)
    return conn.something.something

def home(request):
    c = {}
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    c['myResult'] = pool.map(addNumbers, servers)
    pool.close()
    return render_to_response('homepage.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The home view calls addNumbers and wangs some data back to the page.

However, when a function like `addNumbers` gets huge, I'll inevitably write in a bug and you get the following error message:

> ```
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py
> ```
>
> in get_response
>                               response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
>
> ```
> ▶ Local vars
> /path-to-my-views/views.py in home
>     c['myResult'] = pool.map(addNumbers, servers) ...
>
> ▶ Local vars
> /usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in map
>         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get() ...
>
> ▶ Local vars
> /usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get
>             raise self._value ...
>
> ▶ Local vars
> ```

This just tells me that there is a bug **somewhere** in the function being parallelized, but not **actually which line** the bug can be found in, like a normal error message.

Super frustrating, anyone have any ideas (apart from "write better code" :P)

Comment: May I ask why are you trying to parallelize using pool?

Comment: I have to establish connections with n different mongo servers so spawn n different processes to crunch all the data. Then compile the results.